# Comparing value and removing the lines of a file

Tags: text-processing

I have a file with the below data in `test1.txt`:

```
nnn   90
vvv   80
ttt   50
sss   20
```

I want to compare the second column value and remove that line. For example, if any of the second column value is less than 20, then delete that line entry. The output of `test1.txt` should look like:

```
nnn   90
vvv   80
ttt   50
```

I tried with `sed` and `awk` commands, but it's not working for me.

Comment: What commands did you try that didn't work? Also, I assume you meant less than *or equal* to 20, right?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$2>20' file
```

It checks if the second field `$2` in geather than `20`. If yes, the line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

With `bash`:

```
$ while read -r a b; do [ "$b" -gt 20 ] && echo "$a $b"; done <file.txt 
nnn 90
vvv 80
ttt 50
```

This will read each line and check if the value of second column of the space separated columns is greater than 20, if so it will print the line.

Comment: thanks ..but i need to write this output to a file